# Insert a geovoronoi library polygon to folium map in Python

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, folium, voronoi

To create a Voronoi polygon with geovoronoi lib i use:

```
polyShapes, puntos = voronoi_regions_from_coords(coords, milagroShape)
```

**coords** is a geoDataFrame object that it contains map´s locations and **milagroShape** is a polygon.shp. Now, to plot the Voronoi use the code:

```
fig, ax = subplot_for_map(figsize=[14, 8])
plot_voronoi_polys_with_points_in_area(ax, milagroShape, polyShapes, coords, puntos)
ax.set_title('Diagrama de Voronoi')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Now it works, the graph is showed on screen, but it´s only a mathplotlib plot.
[image: This is the image, but I don´t want like image, I want to put it in the folium map]

I guess that I have to convert it into a geodataframe object (to that, I use geopandas library).
This is the map where I need to put the Voronoi graph:
[image]

Only the polygon of the city´s area is set, but I want to set the Voronoi too.
To add the city´s area I used the code below:

```
for _, r in milagro.iterrows(): #milagro is a geodataframe object
#sim_geo = gpd.GeoSeries(r['geometry'])
sim_geo = gpd.GeoSeries(r['geometry']).simplify(tolerance=0.0001)
geo_j = sim_geo.to_json()
geo_j = folium.GeoJson(data=geo_j,
                       style_function=lambda x: {'fillColor': 'orange'})
#folium.Popup(r['Name']).add_to(geo_j)
geo_j.add_to(mapaMilagro) #mapaMilagro is a folium map object
```

Libraries that i use for my proyect are:

```
import folium #map library
import pandas as pd #Data Frame 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt #to plot graphs
import condacolab #To install some libraries
import geopandas as gpd #Geo Data Frame library
from shapely.ops import cascaded_union #I don´t know what is this xd
from geovoronoi.plotting import subplot_for_map, plot_voronoi_polys_with_points_in_area
from geovoronoi import voronoi_regions_from_coords, points_to_coords
```

Answer (score 0):

> polyShapes, puntos = voronoi_regions_from_coords(coords, milagroShape)

`polyShapes` is a dict where the keys are meaningless (?) numbers and the values are shapely polygons. You can load those into a new `gpd` dataframe.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).